# Use same value for multiple columns in select part of sql

Tags: sql, oracle, case, alias

I am using

```
case 
when condition1 then ....
when condition2 then ....
when condition3 then ....
end aliasname1
```

Now I want to use same value for aliasname2. I read that we can't use multiple aliases for same column.

Also I don't want to use subquery in from clause.

So If case returns value, suppose `10`, I want same value to be assigned to `aliasname1` and `aliasname2`.

How can I do this?

**Update:** Currently I am using it like this

```
case 
when condition1 then ....
when condition2 then ....
when condition3 then ....
end aliasname1
case 
when condition1 then ....
when condition2 then ....
when condition3 then ....
end aliasname2
```

That is using same case(copy paste) for `aliasname2`. Which doesn't really look good to my eyes because of repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either copy your case construct

```
select case 
when condition1 then ....
when condition2 then ....
when condition3 then ....
end aliasname1,
case 
when condition1 then ....
when condition2 then ....
when condition3 then ....
end aliasname2
...
```

or

```
select aliasname1, aliasname1 as aliasname2
from (
  select
    case 
    when condition1 then ....
    when condition2 then ....
    when condition3 then ....
    end aliasname1
    ...
) x
```

Comment: That's what I wanted to avoid actually. :( That's what I am doing right now, using case twice. Still thanks.

Comment: You might create a function as well.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding your question, you can use the same column with different aliases.

This works just fine:

```
SELECT Field as Alias1, Field as Alias2 
FROM TABLE
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5b5c3/1) to show you.

To answer your question,

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN <SOME CRITERIA> THEN 10 END as Alias1,
   CASE WHEN <SOME CRITERIA> THEN 10 END as Alias2
...
```

Good luck.

Comment: That's what I am doing right now, using case twice. Thanks anyway.